# Refresh specific pivot tables when cell value changes

Tags: vba, excel

I have a single cell that uses data validation. When a user selects a new value in that cell, I need 2 specific pivot tables to refresh, not all of them. Here's my code:

```
Sub Update_Pivots(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = Worksheets("Expense by Individual").Range("A3") Then
   Worksheets("Expense by Individual").PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotCache.Refresh
   Worksheets("Expense Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotCache.Refresh
End If
End Sub
```

When I compile this, I don't get errors, but when I change the target cell, the pivot tables do not refresh. Right now this is written as a general module, but I also tried putting under the specific sheet the target is found on (I don't know if this makes a difference, but I thought I'd mention it). Where am I going wrong?

Upated code:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = Worksheets("Expense by Individual").Range("A3").Address Then
   Worksheets("Expense by Individual").PivotTables("PivotTable2").RefreshTable
   Worksheets("Expense Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable3").RefreshTable
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: why are you not using the Worksheet_Change event? Did you make sure that your routine is actually called?

Comment: I changed to reflect this, but it still doesn't execute. See updated code.

Comment: Did you place this routine in the code module of the "Expense by Individual" worksheet?

Comment: I moved it to the code module of the "Expense by Individual" worksheet, as you mentioned, and now it errors on the first worksheets line, saying "Unable to get the PivotTables property of the Worksheet class".

Comment: ahh, now the serious debugging work starts :)

Comment: I think all you need now is to check the names of the pivot tables and make sure that PivotTable2 is located in sheet "Expense by Individual" and PivotTable3 is located in sheet "Expense Pivot"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up neededing to change the language around the PivotTables piece. I used it as a codemodule, as A.S.H suggested, and removed all reference to the worksheet, as Excel Hero mentioned. Here is the functioning code:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range
Dim pt As PivotTable
Set KeyCells = Range("A2:A3")
If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
    For Each pt In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
        Select Case pt.Name
            Case "PivotTable3", "PivotTable2"
                pt.RefreshTable
            Case Else
        End Select
        Next pt
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `.Address` at the **end** of the comparison and refresh the PTs directly:

```
If Target.Address = Worksheets("Expense by Individual").Range("A3").Address Then
   Worksheets("Expense by Individual").PivotTables("PivotTable2").RefreshTable
   Worksheets("Expense Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable3").RefreshTable
End If
```

**UPDATE**

Try this:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Stop
    If Target.Address = Worksheets("Expense by Individual").Range("A3").Address Then
        PivotTables("PivotTable2").RefreshTable
        Worksheets("Expense Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable3").RefreshTable
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It still will not execute for me. It doesn't do anything, nor error messages or anything.

Comment: That was definitely a problem. But now that it is fixed, try refreshing the PivotTable instead of its cache. I'll update the answer.

Comment: No, I updated the code to reflect your RefreshTable suggestion, and made sure none of the sheets were protected, but its still not updating when the cell is changed.

Comment: Can you step through the code and watch each line execute?

Comment: No, it doesn't let me "Step Into" the code... I don't really know how to tell is my procedure is being called? Shouldn't it be called whenever the target changes? I admit I'm weak on understanding this aspect.

Comment: An easy way is to place a Stop statement at the top of the routine. I'll show the code at the bottom of my answer. This will cause the execution to pause and the Stop line will be highlighted. You can then press F8 to advance one line. Do this slowly and make sure that the highlights advance INTO the IF statement.

Comment: Try the update. Note that this is temporary. Once everything is working, you will remove that Stop statement. But with the Stop in place, now go to the worksheet and update your cell. The VBE should open with the Stop line highlighted. Now slowly start pressing F8 and observe what happens.

Comment: VBE has been open the entire time. When I go to Debug-Step Into, nothing happens. Nada. Its not showing me any of the steps. It allows me to do this on the other 3 macros I have in the file, but not this one, and I don't know why. The addition of the stop statement produces no change.

Comment: Ah, so I moved it to the code module of the "Expense by Individual" worksheet, as A.S.H. mentioned, and now it errors on the first worksheets line, saying "Unable to get the PivotTables property of the Worksheet class"

Comment: If the procedure is in that worksheet, then remove the reference to the worksheet. Look at my UPDATE once again.

Comment: If that does not work, then are you sure of the name of the PivotTable?